# How to delete stash by commit sha

Tags: git, git-stash

Is it possible to delete **stash** by its commit sha instead of dropping by the index using

```
git stash drop stash@{index}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no.  You will have to convert the hash to its corresponding reflog entry, and drop it by reflog-entry-name.

Use `git reflog stash` or its equivalent (but more malleable) `git log -g stash` to walk the stash reflog looking for the commit by ID.  Consider what to do if it is not present (perhaps the stash was already dropped), and/or what to do if it occurs more than once (this should never happen in normal operation, but there's nothing fundamentally preventing the stash reflog from listing the same commit hash several times).

```
git log -g --format='%H %gd' stash | \
    awk -v h=$hash '$1 == h { print $2 }'
```

will print one line per matching hash (assuming `$hash` is set to the full 40-character hash).